# subspaces question involving calculus.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

I forget, what are some differentiable functions that are not polynomials? What are some continuous functions that aren't differentiable? What are some integrable functions that are not continuous?

Polynomials are any terms like 5, 5x, 5xy, 5x + y, etc that don't involve division by variables right? So what is an example of a function here that is differentiable that isn't a polynomial?

Comment: $f(x) = \sin x$ is a good example of a differentiable, non-polynomial function.

Comment: $F(x)=|x|$ is a continuous function which is non-differentiable at $0$.  There are [worse examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Answer (score 2):

1. $e^x$, $\sin x$, etc. differentiable, but not polynomials,
2. $|x|$ continuous, but not differentiable at 0.
3. $f(x)=\begin{cases}0 \text{ when $x<0$}\\1\text{ when $x\geq0$} \end{cases}$ integrable, but not continuous.

They are *very basic* examples.